# Python character decoder

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding

I have a set of files with broken characters. The code below works.

```
    w1252= "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM"
    w1251= "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"

    def str_fix(string_w1252):
        for i in zip(w1252, w1251):
            string_w1252 = string_w1252.replace(i[0],i[1])
        return string_w1252

    print(str_fix("MY STRING")) #my string
```

When I replace it like

```
    w1252="¨ÉÖÓÊÅÍÃØÙÇÕÚÔÛÂÀÏÐÎËÄÆÝß×ÑÌÈÒÜÁÞ¸éöóêåíãøùçõúôûâàïðîëäæýÿ÷ñìèòüáþ"
    w1251= "ЁЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБёйцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю"

    def str_fix(string_w1252):
        for i in zip(w1252, w1251):
            string_w1252 = string_w1252.replace(i[0],i[1])
        return string_w1252

    print(str_fix("# Ïåðåìåííûå"))
```

I get
`SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file  replacer.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details`

When I add

`# -*- coding: windows-1251 -*-` I get `SyntaxError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 0: character maps to <undefined>`

and with

`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` I get `#���������������������`

How can I tell Python to read characters as they appear in two strings in the editor?

Answer (score 0):

For your python files you should use:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

in the header, and write all code in utf-8, all your cyrillic characters are supported and you won't miss anything.

---

Check this out:

```
>>> 'абырвалг'.decode('UTF-8').encode('windows-1251')
'\xe0\xe1\xfb\xf0\xe2\xe0\xeb\xe3'
```

Comment: this didn't work. I get an output like `#���������������������` how to encode `ø` and `Ш` in UTF-8?

Comment: instead of `string_w1252 = string_w1252.replace(i[0],i[1])` use `'blah'.decode('win-1251').encode('utf-8')`  or something, and yeah, your original string better come from the external file, because your source is encoded in UTF-8 already

Comment: `LookupError: unknown encoding: win-1251` on Mac. BTW, it should be `win-1252`, which is also unknown.

Comment: @Stepan added the code to the answer. you need to use `windows-1251` instead of just win-1251, my bad